# SQL Group by top n Occurring SKUs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like so called `billing`

```
sku_code | invoice_id | sku_amount | sku_sale
integer  | integer    | float      | float
```

what I want do is first find the top 350 `sku_code` by `sku_amount`

```
SELECT TOP 350 Sum(sku_amount) AS amt, 
       sku_code
FROM   billing 
GROUP  BY sku_code
ORDER  BY amt DESC
```

I then want to slice the entire table by the table by the 350 `sku_code` that appear above

I assume this would be some sort of `inner-join` via a `sub-query` but i can't figure out the syntax.

is anyone able to help?

the query I want to finally run is but with it only returning the 350 sku_codes from the above query.

```
SELECT sum(sku_amount) as amt,sku_code, invoice_id
from billing 

group by sku_code, invoice_id

order by amt DESC
```

giving me a table that will look like which should have around 20-30 million rows.

```
amt | sku_code | invoice_id
```

Thanks for your support!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the original rows for the top 350 skus.  A `JOIN` should suffice:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM billing b JOIN
     (SELECT TOP 350 Sum(sku_amount) AS amt, 
             sku_code
      FROM billing 
      GROUP BY sku_code
      ORDER BY amt DESC 
     ) s
     ON s.sku_code = b.sku_code
```

Comment: perfect, matches my output in python to the T with less computational overhead! thanks Gordon! also consider me a follower of your blog :)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding right you can just use rank. This will give you all records which have a sku_amount in the top 350

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (
    SELECT billing.*,
           RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY sku_amount DESC ) rnk
    FROM   billing 
    ) TMP
 WHERE rnk <= 350
```

Comment: I've edited my question for greater clarity, let me give this a test run!

Answer (score 1):

If your DB version is 2012+, then use

```
OFFSET { integer_constant | offset_row_count_expression } { ROW | ROWS }
    [
      FETCH { FIRST | NEXT } {integer_constant | fetch_row_count_expression } { ROW | ROWS } ONLY
    ]
```

syntax as

```
SELECT SUM(sku_amount) AS amt, sku_code, invoice_id
  FROM billing 
 GROUP BY sku_code, invoice_id  
 ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(sku_amount) DESC)
 OFFSET 0 ROWS
 FETCH NEXT 350 ROWS ONLY
```

by using window analytic function ( `row_number()` in this case ) in the order by clause without need of a subquery

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=6720d1a41e9e66c7e1522b5a0c7f1409)</kbd>

Comment: this is probably my fault due to my poor explanation and understanding of SQL but I couldn't get this to work (I did want to use this as the accepted answer as you answered first) my profuse thanks to you good sir.

Comment: Yes, that's what I found weird as it does match exactly - it may be my SQL server version, my reporting studio is 2018 but the dB itself is very very old and has never been touched by our IT department!

Comment: @Datanovice OK :), btw the first replier was Error_2646.

Comment: you are indeed correct, my intention was to say of the solutions posted after his, as I couldn't get his to work! teşekkür ederim

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by giving a `row_number` for the rows within `CTE` and use the rows having the row_number less than or equal to 350.

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
  select [rn] = row_number() over(
    partition by [sku_code]
    order by [amount] desc
  ), *
  from [bill]
)
select sum([sku_amount]) as [amount]
from cte
where [rn] <= 350;
```

Comment: Thanks Ullas, I really appreciate your help, I will look into CTE and the row_number functions, I must admit I don't know much about them and I have been ignoring SQL long enough!